# What are the name of this distributions appeared on bitcoin trades data?

Tags: distributions, frequency, distribution-identification

I have been playing with  some bitcoin data that i download from binance API the data correspond to 1min klines there is 1 million of samples that start from 01/08/2020 to 01/02/2022

if i make a frecuency table with 1000 intervals and make a plot of the frecuencies of volume  and another plot of the frecuencies of difference between the close and open prices. I obtain this graphs.

[image]

Those distributions have name or a mathematical expression?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve and how does inferring the distribution of this data help you solve it? Depending on what you're doing, you might not need to know if the data fit any particular "name brand" distribution.

Comment: I actually want to make tests that shows is the patterns that some people see on these graph are faces on the clouds or the have some reason. From this particular question create a random generator for run an stocastic simulation. And learn a little more about stadistics.

Comment: If you can describe the algorithm you used to generate these data, it might be possible to show that they are a specific distribution.

Comment: quite simple you take the 1min klines data a.k.a candlestick that is realworld data. And for each candle if you take for example the volume propertie and if it falls on one of the frequency bins then you sum one to that bin. That for each of the candle.

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought these data entirely originated from some psuedo-random number generation procedure.